# How to start search only when user stops typing?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I need to perform a Search when user stops typing.I know I am supposed to use **setTimeout()** . But with **Reactjs I cant find how it works.** Can someone please tell me how to invoke a method (that will handle Search) when the user stops typing for a few seconds (suppose 5).I cant figure out where to write the code to check that the user has stopped typing.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class SearchBox extends Component {

    state={
      name:" ",
    }

    changeName = (event) => {
        this.setState({name: event.target.value}); 
    }

    sendToParent = () => {
        this.props.searching(this.state.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <input type="text"  placeholder='Enter name you wish to Search.'  onChange={this.changeName} />

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the sendToParent method when the user stops typing.

Comment: Well are they typing in an input element? If so, input elements have a attribute called 'onKeyPress' that gets called every time they press a button while that input is selected. So you could have it so that the timeout is started every time they press a button, but if they press the button again before the timeout has executed it resets the timer. If they haven't typed for X time then the timeout executes a search.

Comment: If you're referring to the actual code that does the timeout search and 'stopped typing' check, then there's plenty of examples of those online

Comment: My method is not invoking on using onkeyPress

Comment: It's case sensitive, 'onkeyPress' won't work. Has to be 'onKeyPress'

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` with respect to your code as follows,

```
state = {
    name: '',
    typing: false,
    typingTimeout: 0
}
changeName = (event) => {
    const self = this;

    if (self.state.typingTimeout) {
       clearTimeout(self.state.typingTimeout);
    }

    self.setState({
       name: event.target.value,
       typing: false,
       typingTimeout: setTimeout(function () {
           self.sendToParent(self.state.name);
         }, 5000)
    });
}
```

Also, you need to bind `changeName` handler function in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I would like to point out that you don't need to bind the changeName function when using es6 arrow syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: For that same reason, you don't need to set `const self = this`.  `this` is already bound to the class scope.

Comment: There is an typo on:
```
state = {
   ...
   typingTimeOut: 0
}
```
typingTimeout is written with an capital O. Couldn't edit answer to fix the typo.

Comment: is **typing** field of state necessary here?

Comment: **typing** field look not necessary.  
And when u'r using arrow function `changeName`, u no need to bind `this` in constructor.

Answer (score 211):

Implement using useEffect hook:

```
function Search() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(searchTerm)
      // Send Axios request here
    }, 3000)

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn)
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (
    <input
      autoFocus
      type='text'
      autoComplete='off'
      className='live-search-field'
      placeholder='Search here...'
      onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: be careful, this will re-render the component

Comment: Simple and work as a charm. This solution need more votes

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The HTTP executes **a single request** with the input value. Thank you!

Comment: Made a codesandbox in case it's any help https://codesandbox.io/s/search-input-settimeout-wszrv?file=/src/Search.tsx:205-417

Comment: pity @AljohnYamaro been ignore. he got a good point there

Comment: @AljohnYamaro, can you explain why it gets re-rendered?

Comment: the accepted answer didn't work for me. I was creating a custom autosubmit form that waits until textinput typing stops before submitting and this answer worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @IndikaK it gets re-rendered because there is an onChange on the <input> element that calls setState every time a key is pressed by the user.

Comment: `delayDebounceFn` is a confusing name, it's an identifier. It's typically named `timeoutID` or similar. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will call the useEffect function once per keystroke rather than just once when the user stops typing, leading to excessive hits on a server.

Answer (score 56):

Another way that worked with me:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.timeout =  0;
  }

  doSearch(evt){
    var searchText = evt.target.value; // this is the search text
    if(this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      //search function
    }, 300);
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group has-feedback">
        <label className="control-label">Any text</label>
        <input ref="searchInput" type="text" onChange={evt => this.doSearch(evt)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this working but it still searches on the first letter as well

Comment: this is working fine untill i put value as state on input field..

Answer (score 28):

This [library](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce) (use-debounce) is nice and simple.

**Setup**

```
yarn add use-debounce
```

or

```
npm i use-debounce --save
```

**Usage sample from documentation**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';

export default function Input() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello');
  const [value] = useDebounce(text, 1000);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue={'Hello'}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <p>Actual value: {text}</p>
      <p>Debounce value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Things that I liked at this moment, things could be different in
> future!:
>
> - Easy to setup & use
> - Less Boilerplate code
> - Modest ratings (~1K) and usage (npm - 200K downloads/Week)
> - Supports timeout, MaxWait and other features

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This answer saved me a lot of time (and code)

Answer (score 20):

I used the debounce function of lodash

```
onChangeSearchInput = (evt)=> {
    this.debouncedSearch(evt.target.value);
};

debouncedSearch = debounce(function (query) {
    this.setState({query});
}, 1000);
```

Somewhere in my render method i have this input field

```
<input
    type='text'
    onChange={this.onChangeSearchInput}
    className='uk-input'
    placeholder={'search by name or email...'}
   />
```

Comment: calling a whole new (huge) library for just delaying a function is not good, right?

Comment: @w3debugger you are right. But I already had lodash in my project for other uses.

Comment: You can also just import a specific function, rather than pulling in the entire library.

Answer (score 17):

I have use this custom hook and it's work perfectly no issue still.

```
export function useSearchDebounce(delay = 350) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayFn = setTimeout(() => setSearch(searchQuery), delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(delayFn);
  }, [searchQuery, delay]);

  return [search, setSearchQuery];
}
```

Use in any place like

```
const [search, setSearch] = useSearchDebounce();

<input onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: This is the simplest, cleanest solution, plus it's generic enough to be used for any value, not just a search field.

Comment: This works really well. (y)

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 11):

I think we can do it in a more simpler and cleaner manner, without abrupting the state parameter which calls the complete component life cycle like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //Timer
    this.typingTimeout = null;

    //Event
    this.onFieldChange = this.onFieldChange.bind(this);

    //State
    this.state = { searchValue: '' }; 
}   


 /**
 * Called on the change of the textbox.
 * @param  {[Object]} event [Event object.]
 */
onFieldChange(event) {
    // Clears the previously set timer.
    clearTimeout(this.typingTimeout);

    // Reset the timer, to make the http call after 475MS (this.callSearch is a method which will call the search API. Don't forget to bind it in constructor.)
    this.typingTimeout = setTimeout(this.callSearch, 475);

    // Setting value of the search box to a state.
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}


<div className="block-header">
     <input
           type="text"
           name="searchValue"
           value={this.state.searchValue}
           placeholder="User Name or Email"
           onChange={this.onFieldChange}
     />
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use react hooks *useEffect* with the use of setTimeOut function since it always return the timer id and you could easily clear the timer with that id as follows

```
export const Search = () => {
const [term, setTerm] = useState();
const [results, setResult] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const searchWiki = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', {
            params: {
                srsearch: term,
            },
        });

        setResult(data.query.search);
    };
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        searchWiki();
     // make a request after 1 second since there's no typing 
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
}, [term]);
```

Answer (score 6):

How about a custom hook?

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

export default function useSearchInputState(searchHandler) {
  
  // to prevent calling the handler on component mount
  const didMountRef = useRef(false);

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let delayDebounceFn;

    if (didMountRef.current) {
      delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(searchHandler, 600)
    } else {
      didMountRef.current = true;
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [searchValue]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return [searchValue, setSearchValue];

}
```

Usage:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useSearchInputState(() => {
    resetData(searchValue ?? null, selectedFilterPos); // replace with your code
  });

  return (
    <input className="Search"
           onChange={e => setSearchValue(e?.target?.value ?? null)}
      />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just use the debounce  from lodash or simulate using setTimeout.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class SearchBox extends Component {
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={ name:" "}
       this.timeout =  null;

    }

    changeName = (event) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
         if(timeout){
           setTimeout((event)=> this.setState({name: event.target.value}), 200)
         }
    }

    sendToParent = () => {
        this.props.searching(this.state.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <input type="text"  placeholder='Enter name you wish to Search.'  onChange={this.changeName} />

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the target will be undefined ins setTImeout call

Answer (score 3):

I made my own custom component like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const InputDebounce = props => {
  const { onChange, ...otherProps } = props

  const [inputTimeout, setInputTimeout] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(inputTimeout), [inputTimeout])

  const inputOnChange = value => {
    if (inputTimeout) clearTimeout(inputTimeout)
    setInputTimeout(
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (onChange) onChange(value)
      }, 1000)
    )
  }

  return (
    <input
      {...otherProps}
      onChange={e => inputOnChange(e.target.value)}
    />
  )
}

export default InputDebounce
```

And using anywhere like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import InputDebounce from './InputDebounce'

const App = () => {
  const usernameOnChange = value => {
    console.log(value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <InputDebounce
        type='text'
        name='username'
        placeholder='Username'
        onChange={usernameOnChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below works well for me :

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const search = setTimeout(() => {
        getList()
        //Your search query and it will run the function after 3secs from user stops typing
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(search)
}, [filter])
```

and add HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" onInput={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)} value={filter} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier now with useEffect and does not need any library

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const FuncDemo = () => {
  const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
   const makeApiCall = async () => {
   try {
      // your axios call
    } catch (e) {
    
    }
   }

    const triggerCall = setTimeout(() => {
      makeApiCall()
    }, 500)

    return () => clearTimeout(triggerCall)
  }, [searchStr])


  return (
    <input 
      name='search'
      onChange={e => setSearchString(e.target.value)}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<FuncDemo/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For React hooks:

First we'll define a component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SearchInputText = ({ value, name, placeholder, onChange }) => {
  // state for keepign search text 
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState(value);
  // state for keeping the timeout
  const [searchTextTimeout, setSearchTextTimeout] = useState(null);

  // handler for form submit (pressing enter without waiting for setimeout to trigger)
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // clear timeout as it'll that would be triggered
    if (searchTextTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(searchTextTimeout);
    }
    onChange(searchText);
  };

  // onChange handler
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  // cancelling previous timeouts
    if (searchTextTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(searchTextTimeout);
    }
    // first update the input text as user type
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
    // initialize a setimeout by wrapping in our searchTextTimeout so that we can clear it out using clearTimeout
    setSearchTextTimeout(
      setTimeout(() => {
        onChange(searchText);
        // timeout is 2500ms, change it to less or more.
      }, 2500),
    );
  };

  // making sure that we clear the timeout if/when the component unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(searchTextTimeout);
  }, [searchTextTimeout]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type="text"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchInputText;
```

Usage:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // your implementation here
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <SortSearchInput name="search" placeholder="Enter Search" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more comments to educate the person asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using functional components and the useRef hook.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Search() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");

  const inputRef = useRef<any>()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null

    const sendData = () => {
      // If the user keeps on typing then the timeout is cleared and restarted
      if(timer) clearTimeout(timer)

      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSearchTerm(inputRef.current.value)
      }, 3000)
    }

    const element = inputRef.current;
    // Set listener and start timeout
    element.addEventListener('keyup', sendData);

    return () => {
      // Remove listener wwhen unmounting
      element.removeEventListener('keyup', sendData);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        autoFocus
        type="text"
        autoComplete="off"
        className="live-search-field"
        placeholder="Search here..."
        
      />
      <p>searchTerm: {searchTerm}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

This approach avoids unnecessary re-renders and utilizes event listeners to handle the search submission when user stops typing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working component template with some useful parameters to get your started.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const initialState = { results: [], value: '' }

export default class SearchBox extends Component {
  state = initialState
  timeout = null
  search_url = "https://example.com/search?q="
  min_query_length = 2
  timeout_duration = 300

  handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    if (value.length < 1) {
        return this.setState(initialState) 
    } else {
        this.setState({ value })
        if (value.length>=this.min_query_length) {    
            this.timeout = setTimeout(this.search, this.timeout_duration);
        }
    }
  }

  search = () => {
    // assuming your results are returned as JSON
    fetch(`${this.search_url}${this.state.value}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            results: data,
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <input
            onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
          />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using react hooks, modified from @anoNewb's answer. With additions:

- prevent multiple triggers when there's still timer running
- add on Form Submit event

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-search-with-delay-oclc0?file=/src/App.js)

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

    export default function App() {
      const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
      const [searchTimeout, setSearchTimeout] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (searchTimeout) {
          clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
        }

        setSearchTimeout(
          setTimeout(() => {
            loadUsers();
          }, 1000),
        );

        return () => clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
      }, [search]);

      const loadUsers = () => {
        console.log("axios call with query: ", search);
      };

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              if (searchTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
              }
              loadUsers();
            }}
          >
            <input
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSearch(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me.

```
const[isReady, setReady]  = useState(true);
const onSearchSet =(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 

    setCriteria(event.target.value);
    if(isReady) {
        setReady(false);
        const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
            // Send Axios request here
            
            props.returnCall(props.RDropID, sortCriteria, event.target.value);

            setReady(true);
          }, 1000)
        
    }
      
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I use this code with Saga? It will help send the latest request. The time on the set time out can be changed. In my case, I used 600ms.

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const sendSearchRequest = setTimeout(() => {
      if (searchText && searchText.length > 2) {
        dispatch(sendRequestToSaga(searchText));
      }
    }, 600);
    return () => clearTimeout(sendSearchRequest);
  }, [searchText]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
 let timer;
 return (...args) => {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
 };
}

function search(){
 console.log('search');
}

const processChange = debounce(() => search());
```

It can be used in input

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="processChange()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a custom hook that works exactly like `useState` hook, it accepts the default state as a first parameter as usual, In addition it accepts a second parameter which is the delay of the state change e.g. `useDebouncSearch("some default value or object...etc", 250)`.
Also, this custom hook returns the previous value as the `useState` does.

Here is the hook, you can just copy it and paste it in a separated .js | .ts file and import it anywhere to use.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useDebouncSearch(defaultState, delay = 350) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(defaultState);
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(defaultState);

    useEffect(() => {
        const delayFn = setTimeout(() => setSearch(searchQuery), delay);
        return () => clearTimeout(delayFn);
    }, [searchQuery, delay]);

    const setSearchQueryWithPreviousValue = (value: any) => {
        setSearchQuery((prevValue) => {
            if (typeof value === "function") {
                return value(prevValue);
            }
            return value;
        });
    };

    return [search, setSearchQueryWithPreviousValue];
}
```

***Improved version*** of the hook that will reset the timeout if the user keep changing before the timeout is finished, so it will be changed only if the user stops writing for the specified timeout:-

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function useDebouncedSearch(defaultState, delay = 350) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(defaultState);
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(defaultState);
    const timeoutRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (timeoutRef.current) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
        }

        timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setSearch(searchQuery);
        }, delay);

        return () => {
            if (timeoutRef.current) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
            }
        };
    }, [searchQuery, delay]);

    const setSearchQueryWithPreviousValue = (value) => {
        setSearchQuery((prevValue: any) => {
            if (typeof value === "function") {
                return value(prevValue);
            }
            return value;
        });
    };

    return [search, setSearchQueryWithPreviousValue];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

User [lodash](https://lodash.com) javascript library and use `[_.debounce][1]`

```
changeName: _.debounce(function (val) {
  console.log(val)                
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score -4):

Problem of Typeahead library https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Since the case here is simple, I can use a quick and dirty solution:

```
onChange: (event) ->
  if @_timeoutTask?
    clearTimeout @_timeoutTask

  @_timeoutTask = setTimeout (=>
    @sendToParent event.target.value
    clearTimeout @_timeoutTask
  ), 5000
```

In this way, the task will be triggered 5s after input event. If new event happens, the old task will be cancelled and a new task is scheduled, then it's another 5s to wait.

The difference in React is  the where to store the computation state like `_timeoutTask`. The file scope, the component state, or the component instance.

Since `_timeoutTask` is component level, it should be be store globally. And it does not affect rendering, so not in component state too. So I suggest attaching it to component instance directly.