# How to create a search component that will search a REST API in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to create a component that will search a REST API through an axios request, and then return a list of the results. Right now, I'm facing an issue where all I am getting when I search is 'undefined' and I have no clue why. Any and all suggestions would be amazing.

Users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { search } from './utils';
import Users from './UsersDelete';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: null,
    loading: false,
    value: ''
  };

  search = async val => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const res = await search(
      `https://zuul-stage.whatifops.com/v1/user/email/${val}`
    );
    const users = await res.data.results;

    this.setState({ users, loading: false });
  };

  onChangeHandler = async e => {
    this.search(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  get renderUsers() {
    let users = <h1>There's no movies</h1>;
    if (this.state.movies) {
      users = <Users list={this.state.users} />;
    }

    return users;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
          placeholder='Type something to search'
        />
        {this.renderUsers}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

User.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { truncStr } from './utils';

const User = props => {
  const { id, email, phone } = props.item;

  return (
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div className={classes.VoteContainer}>
        <span className={classes.Vote}>{email}</span>
      </div>

      <div className={classes.Bottom}>
        <h3 className={classes.Title}>{truncStr(phone, 19)}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default User;
```

UsersDelete.js

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './User';

const Users = ({ list }) => {
  let cards = <h3>Loading...</h3>;

  if (list) {
    cards = list.map((m, i) => <User key={i} item={m} />);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{cards}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

utils.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const truncStr = (string, limit) => {
  return string.length > limit
    ? string
        .trim()
        .substring(0, limit - 3)
        .trim() + '...'
    : string;
};

const resources = {};

const makeRequestCreator = () => {
  let cancel;

  return async query => {
    if (cancel) {
      // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
      cancel.cancel();
    }
    // Create a new CancelToken
    cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();
    try {
      if (resources[query]) {
        // Return result if it exists
        return resources[query];
      }
      const res = await axios(query, { cancelToken: cancel.token });

      const result = res.data.results;
      // Store response
      resources[query] = result;

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        // Handle if request was cancelled
        console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
      } else {
        // Handle usual errors
        console.log('Something went wrong: ', error.message);
      }
    }
};
};

export const search = makeRequestCreator();
```

**Update: This is the response info after I called console.log(res) after the search function 
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `res`, after the `search` call?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb it's coming up as 'undefined' after the call, and console.log(res) is showing a correct 200 response, but ONLY with the FIRST letter that was typed in

Comment: Looks like you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217121/searching-in-react-when-user-stops-typing)

Comment: Not really. I'm looking more to just search a REST API with axios, and then I want that list to show the results

Comment: The first letter is going to the REST API because you call `search` in the onChange handler, and the onChange handler is triggered for every key that you type in. So, if you want to wait for some time before you make the call, you need to use the solutions in the links that I've provided to do so.

Comment: what if i just wanted to make the call on a button click after the input is there?

Comment: Then just call the search function on the button's onClick handler. You already have the value of the input in `this.state.value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong with your code:

- There is no `results` property on the data returned from the REST API
- You don't need to `await` on this line: `const users = await res.data.results;`
- There is no `movies` property on your state

I created a codesandbox to test your solution, here is an updated version: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-browser-tz4p6

I have removed a few things from the `User.js` file that were not necessary (for my tests)

Comment: this looks like a good solution, however i'm still getting an undefined response

Comment: if the string to be searched is empty, the result is an error, so the `catch` block is executed. I have updated it to return an empty array

Comment: oh! so i see that it's kind of working now, I see what you did. however, it's only sending the first letter of the input to the Rest API. how could we fix this?

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.