# on toggling, Search Box value is not getting updated [React + Redux]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Currently I am working on a project where i am using react and redux to build it.

**Scenario**

1. There is a toggle button which will toggle between *Group Queue and My Queue*. Both these will hit a api and load the data(list of tickets) .[i.e. 2 separate entities]
2. Now there is a search box while will give the result based on the value i enter. I have added the '[Delay functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212683/12210002)' i.e. after 2 seconds onChange event will fire and it will dispatch an action to all reducers.

[image]

**Problem**

*Let's say, i search for a value(68) under group Queue, it works fine. Now if i toggle to my queue, SearchBox value should be null.but it shows as 68*
As i told, both queue are separate bodies, if i toggle, searchBox's value should disappear, but its not.

**Reason**

1. i am storing a state of search box value and timer  to set the value on typing after 2 seconds and on every character I type, setTimeOut and clearTimeOut will be invoked to accommodate the [delay functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212683/12210002).
2. Thus i have a state inside my React SearchBox Component and once i type and stay put for 2 seconds, then it will dispatch the action via useEffect/ComponentDidUpdate.
3. i decided to have a state inside the component as i did not want to fire an action on every character user types. Only the intended search Value Redux should store.

**Things i tried**

1. i tried with getDerivedStateFromProps, but as i need to use SetState and its asynchronous, its not reflecting the current value.
2. i have added 2 functionality (onChange and OnEnter). With OnEnter, i think it will work as i can pass the redux store's value and action to the input's value and OnEnter attribute. [i have not tried]
3. But i want to have the delay functionality. Can anyone suggest an alternative ?

**Codes**

*1. SearchComponent*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { filterAction } from "../../actions";
import "./search.css";

const WAIT_INTERVAL = 2000;
const ENTER_KEY = 13;

const Search = (props) => {
  console.log("search", props.value);
  let [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  let [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (timer) props.filterAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value);
      }, WAIT_INTERVAL)
    );
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [value]);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      props.searchAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value);
    }
  };

  //  GETDERIVEDSTATEFROMPROPS
  // if (props.value !== value) {
  //   setValue("");
  //   // console.log("check2", props.value, value);
  // }

  return (
    <input
      className="search-box"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search any Request Id/ Email Id..."
      aria-label="Search"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    ></input>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  value: store.filterValues.searchFilter,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { filterAction })(Search);
```

2. *Redux Redcuer* (FilterReducer) -- working fine i.e. on toggling, searchValue is getting emptied('').

```
export const filterReducer = (filterValues = {}, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "TOGGLE_QUEUE":
          return {
            order: [],
            tileFilter: action.payload.tileType,
            searchFilter: "",
            buttonFilter: {},
            timelineFilter: "all",
          };
       case "SEARCH_FILTER":
           let arr = [...filterValues.order];
           arr.push("SEARCH_FILTER");
           let ob = {
              ...filterValues,
              searchFilter: action.payload.value,
              order: arr,
           };
          return ob;
         }
      return filterValues;
    };
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions.

**EDIT 1**
i tried with props.value on UseEffect, now the **search itself is not working..**

```
useEffect(() => {
    // setValue(props.value); // not working

    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (timer) props.filterAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value);
      }, WAIT_INTERVAL)
    );
    setValue(props.value); // not working

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [props.value]);
```

**Edit2**

i added a separate useffect as suggested by Sabbit, but if i type 68, the search functionality is getting invoked on 6 and typed value (68) alternatively.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (timer && value.length > 0)
          props.filterAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value);
      }, WAIT_INTERVAL)
    );
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== props.value) setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using another useEffect for props.value?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimer(
    setTimeout(() => {
       if (timer && value.length > 0) props.filterAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value);
    }, WAIT_INTERVAL)
  );
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [value]);

useEffect(() => {
   setValue(props.value);
}, [props.value]);
```

That will update the value in the state each time the props.value is changed. I believe the `searchValue` from reducer is passed via props to the `Search` component.

**Update**: I have updated the condition to execute `props.filterAction("SEARCH_FILTER", value)` from `if(timer)` to `if(timer && value.length > 0)`. We need to do that because everytime the props changes we are setting the `value` in state and we have used an useEffect depending on the change of `value` in state. That is why it is searching with empty string. We need to make sure that the searching doesn't happen unless we have something in the input field.

Comment: i tried that , now the search is not happening.. Please see the edit1 section

Comment: you can create multiple useEffect. You are not supposed to update the previous useEffect just add another useEffect under that.

Comment: I have update my code. Please look at that. Your previous useEffect should be as it was. Just add another useEffect method call after that.

Comment: You are not declaring any timer in the 2nd useEffect so you should not clear anything there.

Comment: hi, nope.. though its clearing the value on every toggle, but the searching is happening on every second.. like its automatically invoking an empty value and typed value on each second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223910/discussion-between-sabbir-alam-and-tedd).

Comment: I have updated the first useEffect code a bit. Please check now. I will add an explanation in my answer now.