# Why my debounce functionality is not working in a React app with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to fire a fetch request to get data from an API after some delay. In my particular case, I have an input field where a user can input a post ID. I don't want fire a fetch request on each number entered  in an input field. I want to fire a request only after a user stopped entering data for 1 second. Here is my implementation:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timeoutId
  return function (...args) {
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args)
    }, ms)
  }
}

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const fetchData = async () => {
    if (input !== '') {
      let res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${input}`)
      let resData = await res.json()
      console.log(resData)
    }
  }

  const fireRequest = useCallback(debounce(fetchData, 1000), [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fireRequest()
  }, [input])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input type='text' onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input}></input>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

For some reason, it's not working. There are no errors, and it looks like my data is not being fetched(nothing logs to the console). What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start search only when user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217121/how-to-start-search-only-when-user-stops-typing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are calling the function only when `input != ""`.
Till then input is not set to the desired value and thus the function becomes a no-op.
This change will however help

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timeoutId
  return function (...args) {
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args)
    }, ms)
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
    debouncedFireRequest(e.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedFireRequest = useCallback(
    debounce(async (value) => {
      if (value !== '') {
        let res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${value}`)
        let resData = await res.json()
        console.log(resData)
      }
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleInputChange} value={input}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ohh, so in my code `useCallback` basically captures the value of `input` as `''` and because I don't supply new value  of  `input` it just stays `''`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, bingo. To be on the safe side of things, just check for whether `e.target.value` is empty or not..for that pass that to the toBeDebounced function :)

Comment: Thank you very much. So, what is the better way of doing it?  Should I just `setTimeout` in `useEffect` and clean it in `return`. Seems to be a much cleaner implementation than this debounce way. Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: well, this is more intuitive. Calling the method in useEffect, keeping a dependency on input will work too. I prefer my approach. Regarding cleaning up, you must clean up the debounce subscription inside useEffect. If you don't do it, your functionality won't get affectetd. It is just that there will be perf issues later on. It is code debt

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const apiCallTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      fireRequest()
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(apiCallTimeoutId);
  }, [input]);
```

1 sec after the user stops typing the request will be fired.

Comment: There will be a batch of request for each character typed after 1 second as per the solution

Comment: no the request will be fired 1 sec after the user stops typing.if you set it to 5000(say) then after 5 secs the user stops typing the request will be made.

Comment: `The setTimeout() function is used to invoke a function or a piece of code after a specified amount of time is completed.` So as the user types something this useEffect will be triggered and after 1 sec fireRequest will be invoked.

Comment: nope ,fireRequest will be invoked after 1 sec only!

Comment: 1 sec for your timeout, the 2nd one for the fireRequest() itself

Comment: then may be you can remove the delay of fireRequest(if that is possible)

Comment: and anyways any api call will cause some delay!

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working well, however,  I'm not sure if it's the way to go about it. I need to test it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458028/6243352) is on the right track but there's no need to keep `const fireRequest = useCallback(debounce(fetchData, 1000), [])` as it seems to imply.

Just fire the timeout, then clear it in the `useEffect` cleanup callback if the component rerenders:

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("1");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    if (input) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${input}`);

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error(res.status);
        }

        setResult(await res.json());
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="99"
        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} 
        value={input}
      />
      {result && <div>{result.title}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note the `try`-`catch` on the `fetch` call and checking `res.ok` rather than throwing when `res.json()` fails.