# track user stop typing in react native TextInput filled

Tags: react-native

I have a chat application , to show sender stop typing we have to handle user stop typing on keyboard in TextInput Filled.onEndEditing is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217121/how-to-start-search-only-when-user-stops-typing

This would be a nice solution.  Using the onChange event and setTimeout, you can decide after how many seconds did the user stop typing and handle that as you see fit. 

For example, only after 3 seconds of no input will it be considered that the user stopped typing.

Comment: ok, it working fine, thanks...but can it be done with out using hook value , cause in my app there is some render problem due other dependency  i can't use hook value to update text input value instead i use some global variable to update textInput value .....

Answer (score 0):

You can used following Property

```
onEndEditing
Callback that is called when text input ends.

onSubmitEditing
Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed.
```

[click hear](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) for more information

Comment: both are called only when returnkey is pressed or submit button is pressed not working when user stop typing ...please help