Working of useSearchDebounce custom react hook
I found this code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780417/26420821
How does it work?
export function useSearchDebounce(delay = 350) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delayFn = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("setTimeout called");
        setSearch(searchQuery);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayFn);
  }, [searchQuery, delay]);

  return [search, setSearchQuery];
}

Usage :
const [search, setSearch] = useSearchDebounce();

<input onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>

If we assume user types "abc" together in the input field with delay set to 5000,
At first, searchQuery will be "a" , it will setTimeout() to run after 5 secs,
Then searchQuery will be "ab" , it will again setTimeout() to run after 5 secs,
Then searchQuery will be "abc" , it will again setTimeout() to run after 5 secs
But when I tested console.log() executed just once,  Why didn't setTimeout() execute 3 times ?
Am I misunderstanding something ?
I don't understand the code

Because of () => clearTimeout(delayFn); which is called whenever the useeffect is rerun due to dependency changes. This clears the pending timeout and creates a new one.

You are not understanding what debouncing does. The debounced function isn't invoked until it hasn't been triggered for the delay duration. In other words, if you keep typing letters within the delay, the callback keeps getting bounced. When you stop typing, then after the delay expires you get the one call.

@DrewReese That's not it, I know how denounce is supposed to work. However, I was not sure why above code worked because I thought components unmounted only when it is destroyed. Didn't know that it would unmount on data changes as well.

Components are "destroyed" (if that's what you want to call it) when they unmount. They certainly don't unmount when updating states, they simply just re-render. Did you mean to say that you didn't understand that the useEffect hook cleanup function runs prior to the next effect being applied and when the component unmounts?


But when I tested console.log() executed just once, Why didn't
setTimeout() execute 3 times ?

Because every time one of your dependencies change (ie: searchQuery or delay), the cleanup function is first ran clearing the previous timeout that had been scheduled, then it runs your useEffect callback to schedule a new timeout.
So the behaviour you're missing is that the previous timeout is cleared when the user types "abc":

searchQuery will be "a" , clear previous timeout (if one exists, one technically gets scheduled onmount), and schedule a new setTimeout() to run after 5 secs
searchQuery will be "ab" , clear previous timeout (so that never executes its callback now), and schedule a new setTimeout() to run after 5 secs
searchQuery will be "abc" , clear previous timeout (so that never executes its callback now), and schedule a new setTimeout() to run after 5 secs

Timeout completes as nothing clears it and you see the setTimeout called log.

My understanding was that components unmounted only when the component is destroyed. I was not aware that data updates also unmounted it. Can you point me to right docs to further understand this behavior ?

@Baxu See https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

@Baxu It's not being unmounted, it's just that the cleanup function (which happens to also be called on unmount), is also called when your dependencies change (see Drew's link for more details, specifically details on the setup parameter).
